# How to apply xpath in xsl:param on xml passed as input to xml

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have one XSLT and XML input for XSLT like below

XML file:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>hi</c>
        </b>
    </a>

    <a>
        <b>
            <c>hi</c>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
      <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:param name="/a//b//c"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="/a//b//c">
          <xsl:element name="celement">
              <xsl:copy-of select="c element"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

How do I transform the XML using XPATH in `xsl:param` in XSLT?

Comment: What is this - <xsl:param name="/a//b//c"/> ?  that is not a valid parameter name.

Comment: Ambitious question. Do you want to change XSLT? Or do you just want to invoke XSLT processor from command line?!!

Comment: can I put xpath as xsl:param and use that for transformation of xml.Basically I am kind of looking for dynamic xpaths to use in xslt

Comment: Elaborating my requirement, I have one xml file to transform and another xml with xpaths as given in the post, I want to pass the xpaths in the xml as param to xslt and source xml, finally I want to transform source xml using xpaths in xml passed as param to xslt. Any possible ways to implement this requirement

Comment: Well, which version of which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? Saxon 9 allows you to pass in parameter expressions, and the commercial version of Saxon 9 even allow dynamic XPath evaluation at run time, either using an extension function or using the XSLT 3.0 `xsl:evaluate`.

Comment: And as with earlier questions about this topic, XSLT is XML so XSLT can generate XSLT, given your input with the paths you could use one XSLT stylesheet to generate a second stylesheet that then processes the other input with the data.