# XSLT Function Return Type

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

Originally: **How to apply XPath query to a XML variable typed as element()* **

I wish to apply XPath queries to a variable passed to a function in XSLT 2.0.

Saxon returns this error:

```
Type error at char 6 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 13 column 50 of stackoverflow_test.xslt:
  XTTE0780: Required item type of result of call to f:test is element(); supplied value has item type text()
```

This skeleton of a program is simplified but, by the end of its development, it is meant to pass an element tree to multiple XSLT functions.  Each function will extract certain statistics and create reports from the tree.

When I say apply XPath queries, I mean I wish to have the query consider the base element in the variable... if you please... as if I could write {count(doc("My XSLT tree/element variable")/a[1])}.

Using Saxon HE 9.7.0.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f="f:f">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="first" as="element()*">
      <xsl:copy-of select="(./a[1])" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
      <xsl:copy-of select="f:test($first)" />
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:function name="f:test" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="frstElem" as="element()*" />
    <xsl:value-of select="count($frstElem/a)" />
    <!-- or any XPath expression -->
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Some example data

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>hi</c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>hi</c>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

Possibly related question: [How to apply xpath in xsl:param on xml passed as input to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246061/how-to-apply-xpath-in-xslparam-on-xml-passed-as-input-to-xml)

Comment: So which result do you expect? You pass in an `a` element which has a `b` child, the result of `count($frstElem/a)` should be 0.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit:  thanks for the input.  This gives me confidence that I'm on the right track, yet the compiler doesn't care about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `f:test()` to return the number of `a` elements in the sequence that is the value of `$frstElem`, you can use something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($frstElem/self::a)" />
```

instead of using the (implicit) `child::` axis.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit:  thanks for the input.  This gives me confidence that I'm on the right track, yet the compiler doesn't care about that...

Comment: @P.Coltharp: OK. In general, if you're struggling with an error message, **please post the error message.** We can't help you with what we can't see. In this case, you have a type error because you declare the function as returning type `element()*`, but the body of the function yields a `text()` value (`xsl:value-of` with a `count()` expression, which gives a number). Do you want it to return elements, or a number? If you want it to return the `a` elements, replace the `xsl:value-of` with `<xsl:sequence select="$frstElem/self::a">`.

Comment: sorry, I was intensely convinced it was my XPath syntax.  Lesson**s** (plural) learned, sir, thank you.

Comment: @P.Coltharp: Understood, the same has happened to me before. Glad we could help. I think it is a good lesson to learn though, that even if you think you know where the problem lies, you post information about *how you know there's a problem*. In the process of gathering that information for a question post, I've often discovered something I had overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is perfectly correct, except that you have passed an `a` element to the function, and the function is looking for an `a` child of this element, and with your sample data this will return an empty sequence.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit:  thanks for the input.  This gives me confidence that I'm on the right track, yet the compiler doesn't care about that...